# jQuery finding and binidng in plugin

Tags: jquery

I think that I don't understand jQuery behavior, within my plugin I want to handle click event for the sliding controls, with the find function it doesn't work, when I grab the element directly everything is fine.

```
jQuery.fn.whoscheering = (function () {
    var el = $(this),
    left = el.find('.nav-prev'),
    right = el.find('.nav-next'),
    bubble;

    // this doesn't work
    left.bind("click", function (e) {
        console.log('left');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // below works!
    $('.nav-prev').bind('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a self invocing function in the plugin, it should be:

```
jQuery.fn.whoscheering = function () {
   ---
};
```

not:

```
jQuery.fn.whoscheering = (function () {
   ---
});
```

If `.find()` does'nt work, `.nav-prev` and `.nav-next` probably are'nt within the element you initialize the plugin on. And inside a plugin, `this` **is** the jQuery object:

```
jQuery.fn.whoscheering = function () {
    var left  = this.find('.nav-prev'),
        right = this.find('.nav-next'),
        bubble;

    left.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('left');
    });
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vuJLw/)